# CakePHP - Get a variable from Post

Tags: php, forms, variables, cakephp, submit

I have a form that looks like so:

```
<?php
echo $this->form->create('User');
echo $this->form->input('username');
echo $this->form->input('email');
echo $this->form->input('password');
echo $this->form->end('Save');
?>
```

And a controller where the file is submitted:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) { 

        }
```

I am trying to get the input from the form as a variable. Something like..

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) { 

          $username = $this->form->input('username');

        }
```

Is this possible? to get an input from the form and store it as a variable to use it for something else?

Thank you all in advance!

Using: Cakephp 2.x

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data

Comment: Thank you for the link, I was looking in FormHelper.. I Should have reviewed more of the documentation.

Comment: @user2673161 be sure to read `Controllers`, `View` and `Model` in Cakebook. Have fun with Cake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you access value

```
$this->request->data['User']['username']
```

Where `User` is name you put in `$this->Form->create()` and `username` is name of field

Comment: Thank you very much, this has eluded me for a while now.